# Unable to call method with parameter as array using reflection.emit

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I am currently using this post as a guide
[How to create multi-dimensional array using Reflection.Emit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250968/how-to-create-multi-dimensional-array-using-reflection-emit) but using a single dimensional array.

My function looks like

```
public void CallMethod3(object[] Items)
{

}
```

and my reflection emit code looks like

```
MethodInfo invokerMethod = typeof(Foo).GetMethod("CallMethod3");
il.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);

// var local = new int[1];
LocalBuilder local = il.DeclareLocal(typeof(object[]));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof(object[]).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(int) }));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, local);

// il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, local);
// il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
// il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 123);
// var setMethod = typeof(object[]).GetMethod("Set");
// il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, setMethod);

il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, local);

il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, invokerMethod);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Everything works fine and I can hit the breakpoint at the method. However, I start facing problem when I try to populate the object array (code commented out here). I start getting invalid invocations.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you're creating a one-dimensional array, why not use [`newarr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.newarr)?

Comment: I'm no IL expert, but Array doesn't have a `Set` method. Are you looking for `SetValue`?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: One of the `stelem` instructions would be better.

Comment: Yeah, like [stelem.ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.stelem_ref?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @madreflection I used the link as the guide, hence I used newobj

Comment: The linked solution is over-engineered for a single dimension because multiple dimensions require more work.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior AFAIK, I assumed Set would be available just as it is in the guide

Comment: @madreflection Can you post an answer? I'll quickly give it a try

Comment: Here's a general-purpose tip: try putting the code you want to produce into LINQPad and switch to the IL tab. That can help you see what instructions you actually want, and work your way back from there.

Comment: Or try [this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABGgQMIEDeOB1RhyALAQLIAUAlBVTdwG4CGAJwIQA9gGM+EAgF4CAOwCmAdwIiARgCsFY4AG10AXQDcXbtVESIugAwGZBdKjwnsZmiUkQmC4AAsRMHgsFpJsLtwAvqYE0fhEjB4QXj7+gSzqWjq6dgCSwAoAtgDObNGUrjRR2BFAA=). :)

Comment: @yaakov The reason why I am not going for that approach is because I am trying to generate proxies on the fly.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I could never understand box and stelem ref. Could you tell me what they are used for?

Comment: @Crimson7: yaakov is simply suggesting that you use SharpLab.io (as an alternative to LINQPad) to figure out what IL opcodes to use to generate your proxies on the fly, not that you write static code.

Comment: I cannot. As I said, I am not an IL expert. The only way I'm able to make it look like I know anything is that I've gotten really good at using LINQPad and Google. I used LINQPad to see what instructions appear, and then I used google to find the docs for those instructions. The docs that I linked to say "Replaces an array element at the supplied index with the `ref` value (type O) on the stack." Comparing that with other stelem instructions, and comparing the LINQPad output when I change the array type to `int[]`, I'm guessing `object`s have a `ref` type, so you have to use `stelem.ref` here.

Comment: I gotta say, SharpLab really made my work a lot easier. Thanks @yaakov. Plus I also looked into documentation for those OpCodes, and they make a lot more sense now. Thanks everyone!